# Rails how to find record by association's ids contain array

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

course has_many tags by has_and_belongs_to, now given two id of tags, [1, 2], how to find all courses that have those both two tags

`Course.joins(:tags).where("tags.id IN (?)" [1, 2])` will return record that have one of tags, not what I wanted

```
# app/models/course.rb
has_and_belongs_to_many :tags



# app/models/tag.rb
has_and_belongs_to_many :courses
```

Comment: I guess it will return all the records with `tags.id = 1`and `tags.id = 2`.

Comment: maybe not work because tags is a association and id can't equal 1 and at the same time equal 2

Comment: Post your models with their associations.

Comment: Try with this `Course.joins(:tags).where("tags.id" => [1, 2])`

Comment: Are you using PostgreSQL? If so you can use the [`ALL`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-ALL) operator.

Comment: this will return all courses have tag.id equal 1 OR tag.id equal 2, same with using `IN`

Comment: @Vapire I am using PostgreSQL, but I am new to PostgreSQL, could you please give me the full code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468572/postgresql-where-all-in-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a single request, but might still be as quick as other solutions, and can work for any arbitrary number of tags.

```
tag_ids = [123,456,789,876] #this will probably come from params
@tags = Tags.find(tag_ids)
course_ids = @tags.inject{|tag, next_tag| tag.course_ids & next_tag.course_ids} 
@courses = Course.find(course_ids)
```

Comment: this works, thanks, I am gonna wait for some time to see if there are more better answer

Answer (score 7):

Since you're working with PostgreSQL, instead of using the IN operator you can use the ALL operator, like so:

```
Course.joins(:tags).where("tags.id = ALL (?)", [1, 2])
```

this should match all ids with an AND instead of an OR.

Comment: still not work:
`Course.joins(:tags).where("tags.id ALL (?)", [1, 2])`

`: SELECT "courses".* FROM "courses" INNER JOIN "courses_tags" ON "courses_tags"."course_id" = "courses"."id" INNER JOIN "tags" ON "tags"."id" = "courses_tags"."tag_id" WHERE (tags.id ALL (1,2))
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ALL"
LINE 1: ...gs"."id" = "courses_tags"."tag_id" WHERE (tags.id ALL (1,2))
                                                             ^
`

Comment: Thanks, I forgot the `,` after the where string.

Comment: I think you need to use an operator, as well… edited my answer.

Comment: Use PostgreSQL array syntax:
`Course.joins(:tags).where("tags.id = ALL (?)", '{1, 2}')`

Answer (score 0):

referring to [@Vapire's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23754907/rails-how-to-find-record-by-associations-ids-contain-array/23757137#23757137) answer

```
Course.joins(:tags).where("tags.id = ALL ('{?}')", [1, 2])
```