# Where ALL IN, not any, but exactly all elements match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord, relational-division

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ingredients
end

class Recipe::Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  # also has `require_in_filter` boolean attribute
end
```

I want get all recipes by products ids where all these products are in ingredients with require_in_filter = true.
For example, a recipe has 2 ingredients: both with require_in_filter = true and they are referencing products with ids of 2 and 3.

- Query for recipes with products (2,3) MUST return this recipe.
- Query for recipes with products (2,3,17) MUST NOT return this recipe.
- Query for recipes with products (2) MUST NOT return this recipe.

What I tried so far:

```
Recipe.joins(:ingredients)
.where('recipe_ingredients.require_in_filter = ? AND recipe_ingredients.product_id IN (?)', true, [3,4])
.distinct
```

But this query returns recipes with ANY of the product ids (3 or 4 in this case). But I need only recipes with ALL of these products.

I found similar question  [PostgreSQL where all in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468572/postgresql-where-all-in-array) but doesn't help.

```
Recipe.joins(:ingredients)
.select('COUNT(*) AS count, recipes.*')
.where('recipe_ingredients.require_in_filter = ? AND recipe_ingredients.product_id IN (?)', true, [3,4])
.group('recipes.id').having('count(*) = ?', 2)
```

always return empty array

This raw sql

```
select recipes.*
from recipes 
join recipe_ingredients
on recipe_ingredients.recipe_id = recipes.id
where not exists(
    select * from recipe_ingredients ri 
    where ri.recipe_id = recipes.id
    and ri.product_id not in(2,3,17)        
)
and recipe_ingredients.require_in_filter = true
group by recipes.id
```

returns recipe with 2 and 3 as the only required products, but it shouldn't because 17 also must be required.

My SQL knowledge isn't sufficient to accomplish this task

Answer (score 0):

Your second query doesn't work because you're `GROUP`ing by `recipes.id` when – if I understand correctly – you want to query on the count of distinct `product_id`, so try `GROUP`ing by that:

```
Recipe.joins(:ingredients)
.where('recipe_ingredients.require_in_filter = ? AND recipe_ingredients.product_id IN (?)', true, [3,4])
.group('recipe_ingredients.product_id').having('COUNT(*) = ?', 2)
```

Comment: This gives an error: `PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "recipes.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`