# strange sql query implementation joining tables

Tags: sql, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I need some help with an SQL query. Let me describe the scenario

I have three tables, `dispensaries`, `goods` and `products`.

`products` records has two `fk`, `good_id` and `dispensary_id` that let me access from dispensaries to goods through products.
Also goods has an attribute called `name`

Now the situation i wanna resolve is the following:

For a provided set of goods names (`[good_name1, good_name2, etc]`) i want to get all the dispensaries that has ALL the goods in the array ( the goods that matches with those names ).

Let me add an example:

```
 good1 whose names is  good_1 belongs to dispensary1
 good1 whose names is  good_1 belongs to dispensary2
 good2 whose names is  good_2 belongs to dispensary1
```

so i need to create an SQL query that with a provided array of goods `[good1, good2]` returns the only the  `dispesary1`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to turn this into a function that accepts an array of the goods.name items that you are after. First I would get the syntax and format of the data correct though. Try the following from a query window to see if it gets you the data you want with a static list of goods.name text items.

```
SELECT dispensary.id, dispensary.name
FROM products
LEFT JOIN goods ON goods.id = products.goods_id
LEFT JOIN dispensary ON dispensary.id = products.dispensary_id
WHERE goods.name IN ([good_name1, good_name2, etc])
AND dispensary.id IS NOT NULL;
```

EDIT

To return only the dispensaries with ALL items in the array try (modified reference from @ErwinBrandstetter answer [PostgreSQL where all in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468572/postgresql-where-all-in-array)):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_dispensaries_with_all_products(_user_arr string[])
  RETURNS SETOF dispensary AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    _sql text := '
    SELECT d.*
    FROM   products p
    JOIN   dispensary d ON d.id = p.dispensary_id';
    i int;
BEGIN

FOREACH i IN ARRAY _user_arr LOOP
    _sql  := _sql  || '
    JOIN   goods g' || i || ' ON g|| i || '.id = p.good_id';
END LOOP;

_sql  := _sql  || '
    WHERE  d.id IS NOT NULL ';

FOREACH i IN ARRAY _user_arr LOOP
    _sql  := _sql  || '
    AND    g' || i || '.name = ' || _user_arr[i];
END LOOP;

-- RAISE NOTICE '%', _sql;
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE _sql;

END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Comment: Not what i need, check that IN clause just give me all the dispensaries that has a good that is inside the array i'm providing it, but i need that all the goods from the array to belongs to the dispensary in order to return it

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve that is to use `INTERSECT`, generating a set for each of the clauses — which means you would have to unfold the list into *n* queries, one for each item:

```sql
SELECT dispensary.id, dispensary.name
FROM products
INNER JOIN goods ON goods.id = products.goods_id
INNER JOIN dispensary ON dispensary.id = products.dispensary_id
WHERE goods.name = 'good_1'
INTERSECT
SELECT dispensary.id, dispensary.name
FROM products
INNER JOIN goods ON goods.id = products.goods_id
INNER JOIN dispensary ON dispensary.id = products.dispensary_id
WHERE goods.name = 'good_2'
INTERSECT
SELECT dispensary.id, dispensary.name
FROM products
INNER JOIN goods ON goods.id = products.goods_id
INNER JOIN dispensary ON dispensary.id = products.dispensary_id
WHERE goods.name = 'good_3'
```

That way, you'll only get results that are in all sets.