# Hibernate: Many to Many contains specific IDs using Criteria

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, criteria

I'm developing a JPA application where I've reached a problem with Many To Many association between these entities:

**Movie**

```
class Movie {
    @Id 
    String id;

    ...

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "movie_category",
        joinColumn = @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<>();
}
```

**Category**

```
class Category {

    @Id
    String id;
    ...
}
```

I want to select only the movies having all the categories (`List<Category>` for instance). In Criteria API, I could do something like this:

```
List<Category> requiredCategories = ... //from request


CriteriaBuilder b = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Movie> cq = b.createQuery(Movie.class);
Root<Movie> r = cq.from(Movie.class);

Expression<Set<Category>> categories = r.get(Movie_.categories);

Predicate predicate = b.and();
for(Category c : requiredCategories) {
    predicate = b.and(predicate, b.isMember(c, categories));
}
```

Which works fine, but the problem is that I have to fetch `Category` objects from `Category` table first and then use it in `isMember` function. I would like to do it somehow avoiding joining `Category` table.

For example: I want all movies having category `COMEDY` and `FANTASY`. (consider these keywords being `Category.id`), so I need to pull by id from `Category` table both entities and then use them in `isMember` function. I want to avoid that because the information `category_id` is already stored in the association table `movie_category`.
In short, I'd like something like `isMember` but providing an `Category.id` instead of the entity.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my best knowledge such a query is impossible using JPA builtin tools since join table is not directly accessible. But this is possible with [FluentJPA](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA):

```java
public List<Movie> getMoviesByCategories(List<String> categoryIds) {
    int matchTotal = categoryIds.size();

    FluentQuery query = FluentJPA.SQL((Movie movie,
                                       JoinTable<Movie, Category> movieCategory) -> {

        discardSQL(movieCategory.join(movie, Movie::getCategories));

        List<String> movieIds = subQuery(() -> {
            String movieId = movieCategory.getJoined().getId();
            String catId = movieCategory.getInverseJoined().getId();

            SELECT(movieId);
            FROM(movieCategory);
            WHERE(categoryIds.contains(catId));
            GROUP(BY(movieId));
            HAVING(COUNT(movieId) == matchTotal); // COUNT(DISTINCT(movieId));
        });

        SELECT(movie);
        FROM(movie);
        WHERE(movieIds.contains(movie.getId()));

    });

    return query.createQuery(em, Movie.class).getResultList();
}
```

which produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT t0.* 
FROM t0 
WHERE (t0.id IN (SELECT t1.movie_id 
FROM movie_category t1 
WHERE (t1.CATEGORIES_id IN ?1 ) 
GROUP BY  t1.movie_id  
HAVING (COUNT(t1.movie_id) = ?2) ) )
```

The sub query is required to produce `and` semantics. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11589741/263116).
Many to many semantics in FluentJPA is explained [here](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA/wiki/JPA-Integration#manytomany).

Comment: Thanks for answer (and sorry for late response), but is there a way to use the FluentQuery as JPA Specification?

Comment: @t4dohx: not sure I understand your question. FluentJPA extends your existing JPA infrastructure and lets you write SQL queries using your Entitites. What do you mean by "use as JPA Specification"?

Comment: I mean if its possible to convert it to Specification<Entity> as I am using JpaSpecificationExecutor (because I want to have it as condition).

Comment: JPA and all API it has (including Criteria API) do not provide direct access to join table. So what you're asking is impossible. I looked on JpaSpecificationExecutor, it has findXXX and count methods. The sample I posted returns a List<Movie>. What JpaSpecificationExecutor API do you intend to call? What are trying to achieve?

Comment: My goal is to produce just Criteria for my prepared query (where clause), where I just pass the criteria/condition to the function (getMovies(Specification<Movie>))) and it'll return list of movies.

Comment: Well, if you just want to return the list of movies, you can use the posted example as is. In case you have another [complex] query, that you want to add a condition to, you will need to rewrite it with FluentJPA. Since Criteria API does not support complex queries like this, FluentJPA cannot produce a Specification.